# Fill Jquery datatables dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have used Jquery Datatables plugin.At first , the content of the table was hardcoded so i did some modfications in order to fill the table dynamically with fetched data  , it works fine  but the search function within the table stoped working and the value of entries number stays unchanged ( 0 ) .
here's the link for the datatable: https://www.datatables.net/download/index

Comment: Do you have some code to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables already ve api for dynamically add rows... check for fnAddData (DOC https://datatables.net/api). If you force new rows in the table they will disappear for example if you use YourTable.fnDraw() because the real table settings will not be altered. Use only fnAddData or fnClearTable to manage your data. If you use the API the search continue to work fine i think.